# How to get Pop up windows or be able to play asong through all my gets/posts in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I'm just showing a little of my code, there's a lot more to it but what I want to know is how I would go about being able to either have a song play the whole time throughout all my routes or to have a pop up window that will play my song .... As I have other sounds that play through out the game but want them to play on top of the background sound

The project files are on github: https://github.com/joestrippygame/game

```
require 'sinatra'
enable :sessions
require_relative 'stats.rb'

# require_relative "trippy_game_functions.rb"
# trippy = Joestrippygame.new 

    get '/startgames' do
    answerphone = params[:playgame]

        erb :startgame, :locals => {:message1 => "Welcome To Joe\'s Games. Click the game you wish to play ."}
    end

    post '/startgames' do
    answerphone = params[:playgame]
    session[:name] = params[:name]

     if answerphone == "Joe's Trippy Adventure Game"
            erb :trippygame1, :locals => {:message1 => "#{session[:name]} Chose to Play Joe's Trippy Adventure Game."}
     elsif answerphone == "Jade's Safari Adventure Game"
            erb :safari1, :locals => {:message1 => "#{session[:name]} Chose to play Jade's Safari Adventure Game."}
     else   erb :startgame, :locals => {:message1 => "Thanks For playing Have a Great Day"}

    end
    end

    post '/answerdoor' do 
     answerdoor = params[:door]
     door = rand(2).floor
    if answerdoor.include?('Yes') && door == 0
        # erb :answerdoor, :locals => {:answerdoor => "#{playername} Decides to get up and answer the door", :answerdoor2 => " #{playername} your in Luck It's Your good buddy Dave." }
        erb :davehere, :locals => {:daveishere => "Your in Luck #{session[:name]},It's Your Good Buddy Dave.",
                                   :message1 => "\"Whats up  #{session[:name]} I'm Thinking about hitting the club up wanna go?\""}

    elsif   answerdoor.include?('Yes') && door == 1
                # erb :answerdoor, :locals => {:answerdoor => "#{playername} Decides to get up and answer the door", :answerdoor2 => " Oh No its The cops." }
                erb :police, :locals => {:msg1 => "\"Fuck #{session[:name]} you answer the door & I'ts the cops, they bong lying on the table\"",
                                         :arrested => "\"Well damn man. That sucks for you #{session[:name]} They arrest you & take you to the police station....\"",:message3 =>"",:search =>""}

    elsif   answerdoor.include?('No') && door == 0 
        erb :davehere, :locals => {:daveishere => "It doesn't really matter #{session[:name]}, cause Your Good Buddy Dave walks in on his own.",
                                   :message1 => "\"Whats up  #{session[:name]} I'm Thinking about hitting the club up wanna go?\""}

    elsif   answerdoor.include?('No') && door == 1
                # erb :answerdoorno, :locals => {:answerdoor => "#{playername} Decides not to answer the door, but it dosen't Really matter cause its the cops and the bust in."}
        erb :police, :locals => {:msg1 => "\"Fuck #{session[:name]} I'ts the cops and they bust in the door and see the bong lying on the table\"",
                                 :arrested => "\"Well damn man. That sucks for you #{session[:name]} They arrest you & take you to the police station....\"",:message3 =>"",:search =>""}

    end
    end
```

Comment: This feels like a job for JavaScript.

Comment: Joseph, please use proper grammar when asking a question, and take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). If you improve your question you'll get more help more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working Now I have a simple pop up window using. Yes your pop up window will tend to blocked by a popup blocker but now at least the user can see that there is a popup window for the background music and allow it or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
window.open('/backgroundmusic','Background music',' menubar=0, 
resizable=0,dependent=0,status=0,width=300,height=200,left=10,top=10')
}
</script>
```